# Attribute error in pygame " AttributeError: 'Star' object has no attribute 'add_internal "

Tags: python, pygame

```py
class StarsGame:

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen  = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width,  self.settings.screen_height))
        self.stars = pygame.sprite.Group()

    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            self._create_fleet()
            self._update_screen()
            self._check_events()

    def _check_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            

    def _create_fleet(self):
        star = Star(self)
        self.stars.add(star)

    def _update_screen(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.stars.draw(self.screen)
        pgame.display.flip()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    sg = StarsGame()

    sg.run_game()
```

```py
class Star:

    def __init__(self, sg_game):
        super().__init__()

        self.screen = sg_game.screen

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/star.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)
```

the error is found while adding star to `self.stars`:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'Star' object has no attribute 'add_internal'
> ```

Answer (score 1):

To add a `star` to a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group), `Star` must be derived from [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) (see [Inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance)):

```py
class Star(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, sg_game):
        super().__init__()
        # [...]
```